# Checking if the characters is the same in the rows, columns and diagonals of a 2D array

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, rows

I have a 2D array (the size is determined by the user, but has the same number of rows and columns) which has different characters store in it. The characters are either `'o'`, `'b'` or `'g'`. I have to make a function/method that takes in a character (which is assumed to only be one of the above 3) and scans the 2D array, if either a whole row, whole column or whole diagonal in the array has only the character taken in by the function/method, this function returns `true`, otherwise, it returns `false`.

for example: if the array looks like this and the character `'o'` is the input for the function:

```
g g b o
g b o o
g o b b
o b g g
```

then the function returns `true` since the minor diagonal is ALL character `'o'`. However if `'g'` was the input for the function, then the function returns `false`, since no whole row, whole column or whole diagonal is only the character `'g'`.

I have the following code for searching rows, columns and both diagonals, but I can't get the code that checks rows and columns to work properly, the code that checks both diagonals works fine.

```
public boolean wins(char symbol){
    boolean winRow = true;
    boolean winCol = true;
    boolean winDiagMajor = true;
    boolean winDiagMinor = true;
    boolean winOverall = true;

    //Checks rows.
    for (int i = 0; i < gameBoard.length; i++){
        if (gameBoard[i][0] == symbol) {
            for (int j = 0; j < gameBoard[i].length; j++){
                if(gameBoard[i][0] != gameBoard[i][j]) {
                    winRow = false;
                }
            }
        } else {
            winRow = false;
        }
    }

    //Checks Columns.
    for (int j = 0; j < boardSize; j++){
        if (gameBoard[0][j] == symbol) {
            for (int i = 1; i < boardSize; i++){
                if(gameBoard[0][j] != gameBoard[i][j]) {
                    winCol = false;
                }
            }
        } else {
            winCol = false;
        }
    }

    //Checks Major Diagonal.
    if (gameBoard[0][0] == symbol) {
        for (int i = 0; i < gameBoard.length; i++) {
            if (gameBoard[i][i] != gameBoard[0][0]) {
                winDiagMajor = false;
            }
        }
    } else {
        winDiagMajor = false;
    }

    //Checks Minor Diagonal.
    for(int i = 0, j = gameBoard.length; i < gameBoard.length; i++, j--) {
        if (gameBoard[i][j] == symbol) {
            if (gameBoard[i][j] != gameBoard[i][gameBoard.length - 1]) {
                winDiagMinor = false;
            }
        }
    }

    if (winRow == false && winCol == false && winDiagMajor == false && winDiagMinor == false) {
        winOverall = false;
    } else {
        winOverall = true;
    }

    return winOverall;
}
```

### Edit

Test Array 1: I have a bit of code given by the school which should display "you win" after a whole row, column or diagonal has only the character inputted in to the function. My test Array 1 is as follows with 'b' as inputted character:

```
o b o
o b g
g b g
```

This did not display the "you win" message even though column 1 is all character 'b'.

Test Array 2 with 'o' as inputted character:

```
b g o
g o b
o g b
```

This successfully displayed "you win" message since the minor diagonal is all character 'o'. This shows that the code for the diagonal works fine, but the rows and columns doesn't work properly.

Comment: What doesn't work? Can you give example failing input and output?

Comment: I had a temporary array where the second row had all 'b's and inputted 'b' in to the function, but got a false right away. I don't really know what was wrong, but it seems to give a false right away after `if (gameBoard[i][0] == symbol)` decided the first element of the first row wasn't a 'b', so it sets `winRow = false`. I'm not really sure though.  :/

Comment: You can either use a debugger or place a few `System.out.println(...)`s to check if e.g. your assumption is right that `(gameBoard[i][0] == symbol)` fails (and to print out the values of `symbol`, `i`, ...)

Comment: In the check on the minor diagonal: shouldn't `if (gameBoard[i][j] != gameBoard[i][gameBoard.length - 1])...` be more like `if (gameBoard[i][j] != gameBoard[0][gameBoard.length - 1]) ...`?

Comment: I will do that and see what was wrong. And yes, you are right, it should be `if (gameBoard[i][j] != gameBoard[0][gameBoard.length - 1]) ...` Thank you! Hopefully there is nothing serious with this code.

Comment: Don't hope.  Debug and verify.

Comment: I checked everything and it seems that after `if(gameBoard[i][0] != gameBoard[i][j])` sets the boolean value to `false`, no matter if the remaining rows only have the character value (which should mean the boolean value is true), `winRow` just remains false. This is the same with "checking Columns"..I don't really know how to fix that.

Comment: please hard code test data array that fails.

Comment: The logic for checking rows and columns is wrong. It starts with `winCol = true` and becomes false if _any_ column has mixed characters. The opposite is desired: Start with false and set true if any column has only the right character (same for row).